# vb.net publishing file location

Tags: vb.net, build, publish

I'm using vs2010 pro and I've created a project and everything works fine. I have added a help file (.chm) to the project and set its properties to "content" and "output if newer".

My project resides on my C: drive in a folder; for example c:\myproject\whatever

When I publish my project, I publish it to a different location (on the network) z:\whatever

The project gets published to that location and the application works fine except for the fact that the .chm file ends up in my c:\myproject\debug directory and not on the network path that I published to. So my app can't find my .chm file after I publish it. It can only find it when I hit the green arrow and build it locally.

How do I force it to put everything in the publish folder that I choose when publishing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the .chm is ending up in the debug directory for an unrelated reason.  Anyway, to get it  into the publish location, look on the Publish tab of the Application Explorer window, and click the Application Files button. Locate your .chm file in the list and change its status to 'Include'

Comment: In the Application Files window, it was there and it was set to "Include (Auto), Required, Include" and so I changed "Include (Auto)" to just "Include" and it didn't help. The file still will not get put in my publish folder. In my compile options, I am still using the "debug" build. Does that matter? Does it only work on the "release" version?

Comment: In that case I'm a bit out of ideas myself. I take it you are looking in the application files subfolder of your publish destination? AFAIK any file that is set to 'Include' will be included. Is there a corresponding entry in the manifest for your .chm? In Properties for your .CHM  what is set as the Build Action?

Comment: There is no mention of it in the app.manifest file. The build action is set to "Content"

Comment: 'Content' is correct. Can you include other files by putting them into the solution folder and including them in 'Application Files'?  If so then there must be something odd about your .chm. Have you tried removing it and then putting it back into the project? Can you tell I'm scratching round for ideas myself?

Comment: Nothing I put in Application files gets copied to the output folder. Well, nothing except the .dlls and other files that I didn't put there. They get copied, but anything I add manually, does not. Thanks for scratching around; at least someone is.

Comment: OK if nothing gets copied then we have a fundamental problem - either something is wrong with your installation, or you're missing something basic.  Are you sure that *anything* is being copied to the output folder? It's not just still there from last time you ran it? What if you open another project and go through the same steps to publish that?